# MVVM using Page Navigation On Windows Phone 7

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-7, navigation

The Navigation framework in Windows Phone 7 is a cut down version of what is in Silverlight. You can only navigate to a Uri and not pass in a view. Since the NavigationService is tied to the View, how do people get this to fit into MVVM. For example:

```
public class ViewModel : IViewModel
{
    private IUnityContainer container;
    private IView view;

    public ViewModel(IUnityContainer container, IView view)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public ICommand GoToNextPageCommand { get { ... } }

    public IView { get { return this.view; } }

    public void GoToNextPage()
    {
        // What do I put here.
    }
}

public class View : PhoneApplicationPage, IView
{
    ...

    public void SetModel(IViewModel model) { ... }
}
```

I am using the Unity IOC container. I have to resolve my view model first and then use the View property to get hold of the view and then show it. However using the NavigationService, I have to pass in a view Uri. There is no way for me to create the view model first. Is there a way to get around this.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing the view through the constructor. You could construct the view first via the NavigationService and pass it into the view-model. Like so:

```
public class ViewModel : IViewModel
{
    private IUnityContainer container;
    private IView view;

    public ViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public ICommand GoToNextPageCommand { get { ... } }

    public IView 
    { 
        get { return this.view; } 
        set { this.view = value; this.view.SetModel(this); }
    }

    public void GoToNextPage()
    {
        // What do I put here.
    }
}

PhoneApplicationFrame frame = Application.Current.RootVisual;
bool success = frame.Navigate(new Uri("View Uri"));

if (success)
{
    // I'm not sure if the frame's Content property will give you the current view.
    IView view = (IView)frame.Content;
    IViewModel viewModel = this.unityContainer.Resolve<IViewModel>();
    viewModel.View = view;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mvvm Light you could try:

[Windows Phone 7 — Navigation between pages using MVVM Light Messaging](http://www.markerstudio.com/technical/2010/07/windows-phone-7-navigation-between-pages-using-mvvm-light-messaging/)

(See similar post: [Silverlight Navigation using Mvvm-light(oobe)+MEF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741820/silverlight-navigation-using-mvvm-lightoobemef))

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that the view-model should be created and registered at application startup. By placing it inside the root DataContext all pages will automatically get a reference to it without any code-behind or IoC tricks.

```
    // Code to execute when the application is launching (eg, from Start)
    // This code will not execute when the application is reactivated
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        m_ViewModel = new PrimaryViewModel(RootFrame) ;
        RootFrame.DataContext = m_ViewModel;
    }

    // Code to execute when the application is activated (brought to foreground)
    // This code will not execute when the application is first launched
    private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        m_ViewModel = new PrimaryViewModel(RootFrame) ;
        m_ViewModel.Activated(PhoneApplicationService.Current.State);
        RootFrame.DataContext = m_ViewModel;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM architecture,then you can pass navigationPage after registering using Messenger. Create a model class (say NavigateToPageMessage) with a string(say PageName) variable. You want to pass string from homepage.xaml to newpage.xaml,then in Homepage viewmodel just send the message like this under the command you binded (say HomeNavigationCommand)

```
private void HomeNavigationCommandHandler()
        {
            Messenger.Default.Send(new NavigateToPageMessage {PageName = "newpage"});
        }
```

In the newpage Viewmodel,you should register the messenger like this,

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NavigateToPageMessage>(this, (action) => ReceiveMessage(action));

 private object ReceiveMessage(NavigateToPageMessage action)
        {
            var page = string.Format("/Views/{0}.xaml", action.PageName);           
            NavigationService.Navigate(new System.Uri(page,System.UriKind.Relative));
            return null;
        }
```

//Assuming your views are in View Folder